# Modify a Magento template safely

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to modify a .phtml template file in Magento (which is located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form) but I'm afraid to modify it directly since it's a core file.

How can I create a simple module to overwrite this file?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto admin >> Configuration >> Themes

Give a package name and a theme name

Then copy this file to location

app/design/frontend///template/persistent/customer/form.phtml

are you using this to add some fields to form. There you have to add field to collection

Comment: First, thanks for your answer.

You mean I must go to my admin panel > configuration > Design ?

And yes I'm trying to add some fields, is there a better way to do it? 

As you can see I'm a perfect newbie I'm sorry ><